# Will Unity become themeable?

Tags: unity, themes

As of now, unity itself isn't themeable - the theme doesn't change - only the window decoration changes, if that makes sense. 
If unity is to become default in 11.04, surely it would make sense for the launcher and task bar to change as well?

Comment: I do hope so, I wouldn't want all that effort of GTK2 artists going to waste...and besides, I love Elementary :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No decision has been made on this yet.

Keep in mind that we will need something to handle having a high and low contrast theme for accessibility reasons; and that is very much a high priority, so we'll have to revisit this after conclusions have been made at the [Ubuntu Developer Summit](http://uds.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Not only a *high* contrast theme, but also a *low* contrast theme (why do people always forget that?) and probably some other accessibility-related themes too.

Comment: Just curiosity, but what is a low contrast theme for?

Comment: @Sense Ask a separate question. :)